# How to correctly create a test in ReactJs with Jest when the function uses an if statement

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

A have a ReactJs application with the following function:

```
export function setTextoZonaNPS(valorNPS){
    if (valorNPS == null) return "Erro"
    else if (valorNPS >= 75) return "<span class='verde fonte_60x'>NPS: Zona de Excelência</span>"
    else if (valorNPS >= 50) return "<span class='verde fonte_60x'>NPS: Zona de Qualidade</span>"
    else if (valorNPS >= 0) return "<span class='laranja fonte_60x'>NPS: Zona de Aperfeiçoamento</span>"
    else if (valorNPS <  0) return "<span class='vermelho fonte_60x'>NPS: Zona Crítica</span>"
    else return "Erro"
}
```

I write some tests for the Application:

```
test('setTextoZonaNPS_set88String', () => {     expect( QuizzesHelper.setTextoZonaNPS("88") ).toMatch(/Excelência/)           })
test('setTextoZonaNPS_set88', () => {         expect( QuizzesHelper.setTextoZonaNPS(88) ).toMatch(/Excelência/)           })
test('setTextoZonaNPS_set47', () => {         expect( QuizzesHelper.setTextoZonaNPS(47) ).toMatch(/Qualidade/)           })
test('setTextoZonaNPS_set-6', () => {         expect( QuizzesHelper.setTextoZonaNPS(-6) ).toMatch(/Aperfeiçoamento/)           })
test('setTextoZonaNPS_setString', () => {         expect( QuizzesHelper.setTextoZonaNPS("-6") ).toMatch(/Erro/)           })
test('setTextoZonaNPS_setUndefined', () => {         expect( QuizzesHelper.setTextoZonaNPS(undefined) ).toMatch(/Erro/)           })
test('setTextoZonaNPS_setNull', () => {         expect( QuizzesHelper.setTextoZonaNPS(null) ).toMatch(/Erro/)           })
test('setTextoZonaNPS_setEmpty', () => {         expect( QuizzesHelper.setTextoZonaNPS() ).toMatch(/Erro/)           })
```

All tests have passed successfully.
I have some questions about the tests and the code that I write.

I need to check the null value first because when I use the null value, it is the same as I use the 0(zero) value.
Is this a common pattern in Javascript?

Am I writing too many tests?
Is there a better way to write those tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple tests could be generated either in a loop or with `test.each`:

```
const matchMap = [
  ["88", /Excelência/],
  [88, /Excelência/],
  ...
];

test.each(matchMap)('setTextoZonaNPS with %p', (value, match) => {
  expect(QuizzesHelper.setTextoZonaNPS(value)).toMatch(match);
});
```

Or this could be done in a single test if it's desirable for the test to fail on first error:

```
test('setTextoZonaNPS', () => {
  for (const [value, match] of matchMap)
    expect(QuizzesHelper.setTextoZonaNPS(value)).toMatch(match);
});
```

It doesn't test for `NaN`. `== null` may be not enough to check for invalid values. `NaN` value is covered with `>= 0` and `< 0` but some invalid values may pass. If the intention is to not allow this, it can be:

```
value = Number.parseFloat(valorNPS);
if (Number.isNaN(valorNPS)) return "Erro"
```

If the function accepts only integers, this possibly needs to be secured too, as well as tested.

Answer (score 1):

I would just say that it's a matter of taste, but in such situation I prefer to put all the `expect` statements in one test `it('setTextToZonaNPS', ...`.

And yes, arithmetic operations use a `ToNumber` operation when encounter a `NaN` such as `null`.